# Accessing variable outside a block

Tags: typescript

I'm rather a beginner with TypeScript (to be clear, I come from a java universe). I'm currently trying to do a mapper like this:

```
public getApercuTypePrestationFromTypePrestationEX044(typePrestationEX044: TypePrestationEX044): ApercuTypePrestation {
        let apercuTypePrestation: ApercuTypePrestation;
        if (null != typePrestationEX044) {
            apercuTypePrestation = new ApercuTypePrestation();
            apercuTypePrestation.codeTypePrestation == typePrestationEX044.code;
            apercuTypePrestation.libelleTypePrestation == typePrestationEX044.libelle;
        }

        console.log("A = " + typePrestationEX044.code);
        console.log("B = " + apercuTypePrestation.libelleTypePrestation);

        return apercuTypePrestation;
    }
```

But it obviously does not work: in the console, I have:
A = A8C
B = undefined

How can i fix it?

Comment: Can you provide what kind of object you pass to this function? Is it possible that `apercuTypePrestation.libelleTypePrestation` is `undefined`?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `==` instead of `=`. 
I have change `==` to `=`, it should work now.

```js
public getApercuTypePrestationFromTypePrestationEX044(typePrestationEX044: TypePrestationEX044): ApercuTypePrestation {
        let apercuTypePrestation: ApercuTypePrestation;
        if (null != typePrestationEX044) {
            apercuTypePrestation = new ApercuTypePrestation();
            apercuTypePrestation.codeTypePrestation = typePrestationEX044.code;
            apercuTypePrestation.libelleTypePrestation = typePrestationEX044.libelle;
        }

        console.log("A = " + typePrestationEX044.code);
        console.log("B = " + apercuTypePrestation.libelleTypePrestation);

        return apercuTypePrestation;
    }
```

In typescript, 
`==` or `===` is used for comparisons not for assignment in order to assign a value you have to use `=`

**UPDATE**

I have also noticed that you are checking `typePrestationEX044` for null the wrong way.

Change this:

```js
if (null != typePrestationEX044) {
            apercuTypePrestation = new ApercuTypePrestation();
            apercuTypePrestation.codeTypePrestation = typePrestationEX044.code;
            apercuTypePrestation.libelleTypePrestation = typePrestationEX044.libelle;
        }
```

To This

```js
if (typePrestationEX044) {
            apercuTypePrestation = new ApercuTypePrestation();
            apercuTypePrestation.codeTypePrestation = typePrestationEX044.code;
            apercuTypePrestation.libelleTypePrestation = typePrestationEX044.libelle;
        }
```

This `if` condition will automatically check for `undefined`, `null` or`boolean`

Comment: Wow, I'm so STUPID lmao. I was so much into thinking there was something about TypeScript I didn't understand that I did not even notice I was using == instead of =.

Hahaha, it works now, thanks.

Comment: No problem. It happens sometimes.

Comment: Changing `null != var` to `var` might change semantics (since empty string, for example, is falsy). Not sure if this applies here, just wanted to remind.

Comment: @Cerberus yeah, we should use this as we needed.